# Keep Bootstrap side menu in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the Bootstrap website, http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html, there is a sidebar with links. I have replicated it on my website, but on the Bootstrap site when you scroll it sticks in place so it is always in view. It also marks each menu item as active when it is in view.

How can I replicate this also on my site?

Comment: What is your current code? are you including all the required bootstrap files, css and js? we need more info.

Comment: Provide some snippet of code to understand your thought.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `affix` javascript from the bootstrap.

You can activate this by adding `data-spy="affix"` attribute to the element you want to affix.

See the full instructions at - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix.

For this you will need either the full bootstrap library or the bootstrap-affix.js script file included.

To ensure the navigation is updated correctly, you will need to update the page markup as well as use the Scroll Spy plugin - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the "position" attribute of the sidebar div from relative to absolute at a point where the top of the sidebar just touches the top end of the window. You can use a javascript event to keep a watch on the scroll bar.